# Recovery of Parameters from Sum of Bernoulli Random Variables with Different Success Probabilities

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

If you have two Bernoulli random variables, $X$ and $Y$ with success probabilities $a$ and $b$, both independent of each other, and we define a third random variable $Z = X+Y$, is it possible to recover $min\{a,b\}$ and  $max\{a,b\}$ from samples from Z (i.e $Z_{1}, Z_{2}, ..., Z_{n}$)?

I know that it isn't possible to recover either a or b, since Z is defined by the sum of a and b, so I'm lead to believe that you couldn't recover the min or max as doing so would effectively identify/recover a and b.

Comment: "$Z$ is defined by the sum of $a$ and $b$" This isn't really true. The distribution of $Z$ when $(a,b)=(0.4, 0.5)$ is still different than if $(a,b)=(0.2, 0.7)$ even though $a+b$ is the same in both cases.

Comment: I guess I was unclear, I mean that (a,b) = (0.3, 0.5) is indiscernable from (a,b) = (0.5, 0.3), sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

$Z$ takes values $0,1,2$ with respective probabilities $(1-a)(1-b), a(1-b)+(1-a)b, ab$.

Given i.i.d. samples $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n$, the log likelihood is
$$N_0 \log((1-a)(1-b)) + N_1 \log(a(1-b) + (1-a)b) + N_2 \log(ab)$$
where $N_i = \# \{k : Z_k = i\}$.

In principle you can try to choose $a$ and $b$ to maximize this likelihood, but I am not sure if this is a concave function, and taking derivatives is a little messy. Maybe you or someone else can try digging further.